# python server-side program to handle email?

Tags: python, django, web-services, email, client-server

What is the easiest way to write a simple Python daemon/server-side program that, in a reasonably secure way, processes incoming messages from an email account? For example, if you have an account 'foo@bar.org' and you have the username/password to the program, you want to be able to have the program read the contents of the email and save them to a database (e.g. with `sqlite`) in Python. What's the best framework/library for doing this? It sounds like it might be overkill to use Django for something so simple -- can it be done purely with the Python standard libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are python poplib (http://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html) and python imaplib (http://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html). For accessing mailboxes.

Then you have lamson (http://lamsonproject.org/), which is not only excellent for sending and recieving mails. But it can also help you with parsing messages, detecting if they are spam or not - look into lamsons code to see exactly what you can do with it.

Then there are many examples of python daemons, which you can periodically run to pick up mails using poplib/imaplib and then save them somewhere using sqlalchemy or django or whatever.

OR you could skip python daemons and rather create small django project for doing all that. Combined with Celery (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery), you can create excellent daemonized backend for accessing mailbox via POP or IMAP and saving stuff to your own database.